# Fedora: Get a list of installed kernels by Date

Tags: fedora, kernel

I want to get a list of installed kernels in decreasing order on the date which they were installed.

Any idea on how to do this? I am on Fedora 20

Answer (score 5):

You can use RPM to list all packages called "kernel" prefixed with the timestamp they were installed. Then use "sort" to sort the entries:

```
rpm -q --qf '%{installtime} %{installtime:date}: %{name}-%{version}%{release}\n' kernel | sort -n
```

Example output:

```
1405648370 Thu 17 Jul 2014 08:52:50 PM CDT: kernel-3.15.5200.fc20
1406750762 Wed 30 Jul 2014 03:06:02 PM CDT: kernel-3.15.6200.fc20
1420254368 Fri 02 Jan 2015 09:06:08 PM CST: kernel-3.17.7200.fc20
```

**EDIT:** To reverse the list, add `-r` to `sort`